# A riddle from HQ

Tags: riddle, poetry

Here's a riddle haiku from HQ:

> I am just on fire!
>
> A fun, diverse distraction.
>
> This ilk but more known.

What am I?

Hint 1:

> **This ilk but more known** would be clearer as **Like this but more seen**.

Hint 2:

> HQ is  a **very** big clue in this riddle.

Comment: Not to be picky, but isn't "fire" 2 syllables? /ˈfī(ə)r/ (you could fix the line by saying "I'm" rather than "I am")

Comment: @dcfyj it says that you can pronounce it with [one or two](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=how+many+syllables+in+fire) syllables, but if you want two, then just remove the just

Comment: Fair enough, was just asking as I consider it two.

Comment: Got you the weirdest answer yet I promise.

Comment: Fire is two syllables...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you ...

> a **Hot Question**?

```
I am just on fire!
```

> Yup. Flaming hot.

```
A fun, diverse distraction.
```

> HNQ entries are often exactly this.  Hot Questions for PSE are almost always exactly this.

```
This ilk but more known.
```

> There are lots of HNQs out there. **OP EDIT:** This is a question, of the same ilk as a hot question, but hot questions are known and seen by more people.

Hint 2:

> ***HQ is a very big clue in this riddle.***
>  Well, yes.

Comment: Perfect answer well done!

Answer (score 1):

Judging from your hint, I believe that

> the answer is either a type of riddle or a type of poem.

With that in mind, the best I can come up with right now is

> Sonnet

"I am just on fire!"

> "Sonne" is German for "sun" - I'm aware that the sun is not actually on fire but like I said, this is the closest I can come up with right now

"A fun, diverse distraction"

> Sonnets can be about anything, and are meant to entertain (i.e. distract)

"This ilk but more known"

> A sonnet is a type of poem, like a haiku, but thanks to the works of William Shakespeare is arguably more well-known

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure but I'll guess you're

> The [Phoenix Suns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoenix_Suns)

because

> *I am just on fire!* 
>  The sun is a fireball.  Also "on fire" is a term used to indicate a team is doing really well in a game (or maybe that was just a [video game I used to play](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NBA_Jam)). 
>  *A fun, diverse distraction* 
>  People enjoy watching basketball, perhaps sometimes as a distraction from their real lives.  "Diverse" could refer to the [team roster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoenix_Suns#Current_roster)? 
>  *This ilk but more known.*  
>  "Ilk" = "A type of people or things similar to those already referred to" so I guess "This ilk" could refer to other basketball teams, and "more known" could refer to teams in other sports that can also be fun, diverse distractions from daily life.

But

> I'm not sure how "HQ" fits into any of that but I'm pretty sure "HQ" is related to the answer -- the correct answer, whether it's mine or not -- somehow.

Comment: Sorry but not what I was looking for.

Comment: Gadzooks!  Foiled again!

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

> Texas Hold'em

I am just on fire!

> Burning

A fun, diverse distraction.

> Cards

This ilk but more known.

> Burning cards... Texas Hold'em?

Comment: Sorry but this isn't the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

> Google Cardboard

I am just on fire!

> **Google**: that feeling when you successfully *Google* multiple things in a row and find your answer.

A fun, diverse distraction.

> **Daydream**: That *daydream* you have during a lecture, it's fun and it's distracting.

This ilk but more known.

> Google Daydream (the VR platform) is brand new, the successor to the more well-known VR platform **Google Cardboard.**

Comment: Sorry, a creative answer but not what I was looking for.